# querySelector works in Chrome console but not PhantomJS using page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, json, phantomjs, casperjs

Trying to screenshot the radar from this webpage https://weather.com/weather/radar/interactive/l/87562:4:US?layers=rwi

I ran `document.querySelector('.modal').style="display: none;"` in the Chrome console on that page, to get rid of the div popup ad blocking the radar image. But for whatever reason PhantomJS is not making the Subaru ad disappear.
 [Current PhantomJS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHdl9.png)

I also tried to run `document.querySelector('.close').click();` to close the ad on the page and it worked in Chrome using the console but not in PhantomJS.

I can run querySelector in the Chrome console and get rid of the subaru ad and screenshot the div #imap but for whatever reason it doesn't work in PhantomJS.

I've tried moving querySelector inside the timeout but nothing changes.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 720 };


page.open('https://weather.com/weather/radar/interactive/l/87562:4:US?layers=rwi', function (status) {

page.evaluate(function() {
    document.querySelector('.modal').style="display: none;"   
    });

    setTimeout(function() {

    var clipRect = page.evaluate(function(){

    return document.querySelector('#imap').getBoundingClientRect();

        });


        page.clipRect = {
            top:    clipRect.top,
            left:   clipRect.left,
            width:  clipRect.width,
            height: clipRect.height
        };

        console.log(JSON.stringify(clipRect));


        page.render('imap2.png');

        phantom.exit();
    }, 6000);
```

Can anyone point me in the direction as to what I am missing here?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this:

```
return document.querySelector('#imap').getBoundingClientRect();
```

like this:

```
page.evaluate(function(){
       return document.querySelector('#imap').getBoundingClientRect();
})
```